# How do you prove that $\log n \cdot \log n$ grows no faster than $\sqrt{n}$

Tags: logarithms

I had to graph it to see it. How can I prove it?

Comment: What is your exact question? Do you want a proof of $\log^2(n)/\sqrt{n}\to 0$ or that of an inequality $\log^2 n < \sqrt{n}$ for large $n$?

Comment: I want to show that $logn*logn$ is of Ordo($\sqrt{n}$)

Comment: It is the former statement I mentioned. I am going to give a proof.

Comment: @Hanul Jeon Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before proving it let us examine the following inequality:
$$\log x \le x.$$
It holds for any $x$. Now substitute $x$ to $x^{1/8}$ then we have
$$\log x \le 8 x^{1/8}.$$

Now the proof is direct: you can see that $\log^2{n} / \sqrt{n}\le 64/n^{1/4}$ for any $n$.

Comment: When you make the substitution it is confusing to reuse the variable.  It would be better to define $y=x^{1/8}$ (or do you want $y=x^8?)$ and rewrite in terms of $y$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we establish that $\log(x)<x$.  This is quite trivial.  Now let $x=y^{1/n}$,

$$\frac1n\log(y)=\log(y^{1/n})<y^{1/n}$$

$$\log(y)<ny^{1/n}$$

Square both sides.

$$\log^2(y)<n^2y^{2/n}=\mathcal O(y^{2/n})$$

Let $n>4$ and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

What is true is more general: for any $\alpha,\beta>0$, $\;\ln^{\alpha} x=o(x^\beta)\;$ near $\;\infty$.

This is easily deduced from the basic case $\alpha=\beta=1$, or directly proved showing that, if $x$ is large enough,
$$\ln x < x^{\tfrac{\beta}{2\alpha}}$$
(compare the derivatives of both sides of the inequality, and use a corollary of the mean-value theorem).